# How to write a conditional range for the Command Button in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a Command button in Excel which would **add 1** to the value of cell **A1** if you click it on Monday, **add 1** to the value of cell **B1** if you click it on Tuesday, **add 1** to the value of cell **C1** if you click it on Wednesday, **add 1** to the value of cell **D1** if you click it on Thursday, and finally **add 1** to the value of cell **E1** if you click it on Friday. Is it possible at all? What code should be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Weekday`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) function on `Date` (today), with Monday specified as the first day of the week.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wkDay As Long
    wkDay = Weekday(Date, vbMonday)

    With Cells(1, wkDay)
        .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
End Sub
```